# Посредством каких классов происходит компиляция Razor в сборку?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net, razor

В ASP.NET проектах можно использовать Razor (файлы с расширением cshtml).

Насколько мне известно, Razor-файлы преобразуются в C# код, который затем компилируется в сборку. Эта сборка загружается в приложение, создается объект Page, к методам которого можно обратиться и получить HTML.

Хотелось бы использовать Razor в своем приложении. Идея такая: в своем приложении создаем WebBrowser, компилируем Razor и в WebBrowser загружаем HTML, полученный от Page.

Посредством каких классов происходит компиляция Razor в сборку?

Comment: [razor engine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/)